# The picture can't upload directly to album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm develop application to upload picture file. 
But the picture can't upload directly to album.
Alway have to approve before upload. How to solving this 
problem?

> Would you like to add these photos to your album?
>   The photos below were uploaded from another application, you'll need to approve them.

Answer (score 9):

You need the `user_photos` permission to upload directly to an album; you may be uploading with the `publish_stream` permission which allows photo uploads but needs them to be approved before they're shown

Comment: This would solve some cases, but not all cases. I have the "user_photos" permission in my access token, but I'm still getting the error message. (Originally I did not... something changed)

Comment: It also depends on the privacy settings. If the album is set to be shared with a larger group of people than the the app is allowed, then you will still have to approve the uploaded photos before they can be published.

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by Igy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13599491/195648) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511757/created-a-new-album-and-uploaded-photos-is-it-possible-that-approve-photos-aut) resolved the issue for me:

> to upload to albums without specific user approval of each photo the
>   Permission is user_photos
>
> One important exception to this is if the user, when installing your
>   app, chooses a privacy setting that is more restrictive than the
>   privacy setting on the album you're trying to upload to - in that case
>   the user still needs to manually approve the photo, because their
>   previous selection for maximum visibility of your app's content would
>   not be respected if you could upload to a more-visible album

Comment: Had this issue because my app was set to "Only friends" and my album was set to "Friends".

Thanks!