# Created a new album and uploaded photos : Is it possible that approve photos automatically?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen many Facebook apps that it upload photos and publish automatically.

C# .NET

```
JsonObject jasonObj = CreateAlbum(accessToken);

UploadPhoto(jo["id"].toString(""), accessToken, filename);

 public JsonObject CreateAlbum(string accessToken)
        {
            FacebookClient facebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            Dictionary<string, object> albumParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            albumParameters.Add("message", "My Album message");
            albumParameters.Add("name", "Album Name");
            JsonObject resul = facebookClient.Post("/me/albums", albumParameters) as JsonObject;
            return resul;
        }

    public void UploadPhoto(string AlbumId, string accessToken, string FullImagePath)
    {
        byte[] photo = File.ReadAllBytes(FullImagePath);

        FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.access_token = accessToken;
        parameters.message = "This is a test photo of a monkey that has been uploaded " +
                             "by the Facebook C# SDK (http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com)" +
                             "using the Graph API";
        var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            FileName = "top.jpg",
            ContentType = "image/jpeg",
        };
        mediaObject.SetValue(photo);
        parameters.source = mediaObject;

        dynamic result = app.Api(String.Format("/{0}/photos", AlbumId), parameters, HttpMethod.Post);
    }
```

But that photos wasn't published at the Timeline.

Would you like to add these photos to your album?
The photos below were uploaded from another application, you'll need to approve them.

Is it Facebook's policy? Or My mistake?

Answer (score 2):

`public_stream` in user1027092's answer isn't a real permission - to upload to albums without specific user approval of each photo the [Permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) is `user_photos`

One important exception to this is if the user, when installing your app, chooses a privacy setting that is more restrictive than the privacy setting on the album you're trying to upload to - in that case the user still needs to manually approve the photo, because their previous selection for maximum visibility of your app's content would not be respected if you could upload to a more-visible album

Answer (score 1):

1) Facebook: edit permissions in page developer app https://developers.facebook.com/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxx/permissions
              - Extended Permissions: public_stream , read_stream

2) C#: add scope = "publish_stream,read_stream,user_photos" in link redirect 
3) Example : https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&scope={1}&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token

replace scope with string in line 2